# How to create a method that takes any object and returns a name:value pair for all properties?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

For example I have a simple class like

```
public class Person{ 
    public int Age {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I need to make a method that takes any class and spits out values of properties set in the  object as a string in format "Age:35;Name:John Doe;"

I am looking for a method signature on the lines of

```
public string SpitNameValuePairs<T>()
```

or something like it. How can this be done efficiently if using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That have protection from crashes when property have an indexer defined and also it output only instance properties (no static).

```
    private static string SplitNameValuePairs<T>(T value)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
        {
            if (property.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}:{1};", property.Name, property.GetValue(value, null));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick implementation.

```
    public static string SplitNameValuePairs(object value)
    {
        string retVal = string.Empty;
        List<string> keyValuePairs = new List<string>();

        foreach (var propInfo in value.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            keyValuePairs.Add(string.Format("{0}:{1};", propInfo.Name, propInfo.GetValue(value, null).ToString()));
        }

        retVal = string.Join("", keyValuePairs.ToArray());

        return retVal;
    }
```

Then called like this:

```
        var person = new Person();
        person.Name = "Hello";
        person.Age = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(SplitNameValuePairs(person));
```

Comment: If you just make it an extension method, you don't need the generic typing.

Comment: I just came to the almost this exact implementation.  The only issue about is I've heard this is very slow (between 10X-1000X slower if I recall correctly).  This also only deals with simple properties (i.e. not indexed, thats what the null argument to GetValue does).

Comment: Your solution is incomplete, you should add check for indexers and filtering for static properties. Since GetProperties() returns array you can use Array.ConvertAll which will be faster.